# Constant Member Functions

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants, member

After reading [this](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html), it is my understanding that declaring a method as `const` prevents it from accidentally modifying the class's member variables.

- Are `const` methods commonly used?
- Should they be used for *everything* that shouldn't modify member variables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `const` should always be used, when appropriate.

It lets your compiler check your application logic, statically asserting [const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) for free!

Some people even say that `const` should be the default, and you should be forced to use `mutable` for what is non-constant.

Comment: Additionally, you can overload functions on just the function's `const` qualifier. This allows, for example, an index operator that automatically returns the element in a read-only* manner if the object is declared as `const`. [*read-only still only applies at compile-time, though. `const` can't do anything at run-time]

Comment: I am thinking about your statement "const as the default, and mutable for non-constant". Seems like an extreme position, but I will try to  feel what I think about it.

Comment: @Stephane: I'll "guide" your reflexion --> when are you likely to screw up your object: when you read or when you write ?

Comment: @Matthieu, So you const-fullprotect the class members of the objects you tend to write to/change often ?

Comment: @Stephane: no, but every single `read-only` method is marked `const`. The problem however is that if non-const method is read-only, the compiler does not tell anything. Whether if a `const` method tries to write, then you get an error. For const-correctness to be enforced, it'd be better to specify when you want write access that being given it by default I think.

Comment: I completely agree for read-only methods, I am already doing it, using const protection. What Peoro adds, is a more extreme point of view ( as I interpret it): There are even people who says Classes should be defined with **const** members as much as possible, and declare the mutable fields only. I must experiment with it before thinking if its abuse of constness ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I use const extensively to communicate design intent. If I intended that a method was a pure query, and not a modification function, I would both enforce that and communicate it with a 'const' in the signature.

I encourage you to look at Meyer's thoughts on the matter of side-effect-free functions, and the implications that has on enabling testing.

Answer (score 4):

Just my testimony.

Some years ago, I was still against the use of const, just because of the constraints in design and writing longer function signatures...  and so on...

But one of my project leaders always insisted, all the time, reminding me: "You should use const function, it avoids accidents and doing non-sense".

And one day I faced an *impossible* bug to find. Days after days after days... A nightmare. The design was too big for me too see so as I could grasp it in its whole. I searched in vain until I decided I was lost.

Then I spent two days redefining **ALL the functions that should be const**. I mean it, two days. (Recompilations were long as it was a 5 millions lines of code project).

And then: simply I found the bug... rather the Compiler found the bug for me: In a getter-like method, which should have given me the prefered size of a gui control, the code was actually computing the size, but it was also caching its size and updating its size... Thus modifying the object.

Now, sometimes I forget to put const. But if I notice it, I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `const` to a member function allows it to be called on const references to an object, because it guarantees that instance variables won't be changed. Const references occur in various places throughout the STL, so it makes sense to mark member functions as const where the function doesn't intend to modify the state of an object.

Note: it is possible to mark certain instance variables as `mutable` so they can be changed even by const functions. This is useful to implement look-up caches, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a method that shouldn't modify member variables:

1. Assures that what you think is what is happening, i.e. that you're not accidentally modifying a variable somewhere.
2. Declares to callers of the function that this method doesn't modify member variables, removing the need to read over the code or rely on documentation that says so.

So yes, use `const` wherever it makes sense. They're not as widely used as I'd like to see though, most likely because the majority of developers don't see the huge benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If you forget to mark an accessor as `const`, the compiler will not allow the method to be called on `const` objects or references to `const` objects. So yes, marking accessors as `const` *is*  important.

Comment: Yeah, I know the pain when people forget to declare getters as const. We've got to work with a framework here which completely ignore the concept and has every member function, including getters, as non-const. Now we have to pass pointer/references as non-const whereever we want to access such an object, even if we definitely only ever want to read... -_-

Answer (score 1):

If you have a const reference or pointer (i.e. pointer to const) of a class object then you can ONLY call const member methods of the class.

So if someone "forgot" to make a "get" method const, you would not be able to call it with a const reference (There is a workaround with const_cast but we don't want to use that!).

So yes, if the class is not going to be modified by the method then it should be const.

Note: there are some occasions that you do want to modify a variable as an "implementation detail", eg lazy-loading or to lock a mutex. In such a case you can still make the method const but make that member variable "mutable".

If you are writing a virtual method, it should be const if no derived class will need it to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the const keyword whenever possible.

**It prevent you from the mistakes in the code.**

**It increase the readability of the code very much.**
Everyone who is reading the header and seeing const keywords can immediately understand that a const method does not change the state of an object and can be used with no being afraid he will change the object for example