# Why is Stack::top() a const member function? 

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T> 
class Stack { 
  private: 
    std::vector<T> elems;  // elements 

  public: 
    Stack();               // constructor 
    void push(T const&);   // push element 
    void pop();            // pop element 
    T top() const;         // return top element 
};
```

Why is top() a constant function? I think every stack should have it's own top element, and so to access it a non-constant top() function. Am I wrong?

Comment: What does the question title have to do with this question?

Comment: It got stuck from a previous question, and I didn't notice to change it. I will change it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constant Member Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691332/constant-member-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` != `static`. `const` means that the function doesn't modify any internal variables and the state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

A `const` function does not mean the result does not depend on a class object.  It means that calling the function does not modify the object.

```
int main() {
    Stack<int> a_stack;
    a_stack.push(5); // modifies a_stack
    int n = a_stack.top(); // does not modify a_stack
}
```

A member function that does not need a class object is declared with the `static` keyword (and cannot be `const` since there is no object to promise not to modify).

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a method that doesn't modify class attributes; maintains Stack constant

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't change any of the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Procedures to see that only the stack top is set to a const does not need to change internally.